# Vim -- map a command to search results

Tags: javascript, vim

I'd like to perform the action `dd` to every result of a search. For example, in a Javascript file I'd like to perform `dd` on each line corresponding to the results of `/console`.

Is there a quick and simple way to do this?

Comment: A better solution would prolly be to do a regex replace on every line that you find the result on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to delete every line that contains the term `console` you can do it using

```
:global/console/d
```

The global command has the format of

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]                                                
                    Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the      
                    lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

For more information on the `global` command use `:h global`. For a list of all the possible values for `[cmd]` use `:h ex-cmd`.